# Css3 bubble, triangle of 1px

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm working with CSS3 and I'm doing some bubbles.

I have a problem, I need to have a triangle with 1px border, but with my code I have a fat triangle..

Here my fiddle : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d3g74/)

And the code :

```
<p class="triangle-border right">hi hi</p>

.triangle-border {
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:100px;
}

.triangle-border.right {
  margin-right:50px;
  border:3px solid #EEEEEF;
}

.triangle-border:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:20px 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#EEEEEF transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:47px; /* value = (:before left) + (:before border-left) - (:after border-left) */
  border-width:13px 13px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fff transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

/* creates the larger triangle */
.triangle-border.right:before {
  top:10px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  left:auto;
  right:-30px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:15px 0 15px 30px;
  border-color:transparent #EEEEEF;
}

/* creates the smaller  triangle */
.triangle-border.right:after {
  top:16px; /* value = (:before top) + (:before border-top) - (:after border-top) */
  bottom:auto;
  left:auto;
  right:-21px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:9px 0 9px 21px;
  border-color:transparent #fff;
}
```

Do you see the triangle on the right ? I need a triangle with just 1px of border.. Thanks !

Comment: That's too much code for a single triangle

Comment: Are you worried about what's happening with FF 3.0 users ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How's this?](http://jsfiddle.net/d3g74/1/)

```
/* creates the larger triangle */
.triangle-border.right:before {
  top:14px; /* controls vertical position */
  bottom:auto;
  left:auto;
  right:-22px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  border-width:11px 0 11px 22px;
  border-color:transparent #EEEEEF;
}
```

I just played with the border-width and top/left positioning

Answer (score 0):

You can see it working Here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z6UM2/)

```
.triangle-border.right:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #EEEEEF;
    border-width: 15px 0 13px 27px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: -28px;
    top: 11px;
    width: 0;
}
.triangle-border:before {      
    border-color: #EEEEEF rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid;       
    content: "";       
    height: 0;      
    position: absolute;

}
.triangle-border.right:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #FFFFFF;
    border-width: 10px 0 11px 23px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: -23px;
    top: 15px;
}
.triangle-border:after {
    border-color: #FFFFFF rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid;       
    content: "";
    display: block;      
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.triangle-border.right {
    border: 3px solid #EEEEEF;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.triangle-border {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Just made it to fit with your current border width, but you can play with

> .triangle-border.right:before

class to adjust it with any border size.

> That's too much code for a single triangle , You can refer this link : [Tutorial On Speech Bub](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/)